# In a django custom field, is it invalid to give the constructor a class-type input parameter?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm trying to define a custom field in Django, and I wanted to initialize it with a helper object. The field class receives the helper object an init parameter, and stores it internally. Something that would work like this:

```py
# define helper class
class Foo:
   # ...

# instance of helper class
myFoo = Foo()

# model with field accepting helper class
class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = FooManagedField(foo=myFoo)
```

This seems to me like a pretty reasonable thing to do.
**But in practice, it completely breaks migration tooling.**

What I'm seeing happen is this: As soon as any model makes use of this field, Django considers it to always be in an altered state (I assume because it doesn't consider different objects equivalent). Therefore, it registers as always have changes requiring new migrations.

Is there any way to solve this, any way to indicate that the definition is consistent? Or is it a blanket restriction that a custom field can only be initialized with primitives?
Or maybe there's a reason I'm not seeing that passing object instances into a custom Field implementation is a bad idea and I shouldn't want to do it?

### Walkthrough and Detail

I'm defining a simple custom Django field, as follows:

```py
class FooManagedField(CharField):
    def __init__(self, foo : Foo, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.foo : Foo = foo
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        kwargs["foo"]=self.foo
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

Where `Foo` is a simple object, e.g.:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n=n
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Foo({self.n})"
```

Now I add this new field type to a model (having written supporting class `FooSerializer` to support migrations -- supporting code below):

```py
from django.db import models
from .utils.foo_field import Foo, FooManagedField

fooA = Foo(1)
fooB = Foo(2)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    n1 = models.IntegerField() # preexisting field
    n2 = models.IntegerField() # preexisting field
    foo1 = FooManagedField(foo=fooA) # new FooManagedField
    foo2 = FooManagedField(foo=fooB) # new FooManagedField
```

Running `makemigrations` produces a migration file, as expected:

```py
    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            name='foo1',
            field=myproject.utils.foo_field.FooManagedField(foo=Foo(1)),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            name='foo2',
            field=myproject.utils.foo_field.FooManagedField(foo=Foo(2)),
        ),
    ]
```

But then, running `makemigrations` again will produce *another* migration file. Running it again will produce a third. With this field definition, there is no final state. All the new migrations will look like this:

```py
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            name='foo1',
            field=myproject.utils.foo_field.FooManagedField(foo=Foo(1)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            name='foo2',
            field=myproject.utils.foo_field.FooManagedField(foo=Foo(2)),
        ),
    ]
```

### Question

Is this a hard limitation in Django? Is there a way to provide a class, like I'd like to?

And, is the fact that I want this construction to begin with, a sign I'm making mistakes in my code design? Am I coming at this in the wrong way -- does it not make sense to encapsulate some reusable logic into a helper class that defines the field?

### References

- [Infinite AlterField Migrations due to default callable object mismatch](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32689) is an existing ticket which helped me figure out what the immediate issue was (though I'm still missing the rationale and a workaround, or else to understand why this shouldn't be worked around)
- [`non_db_attrs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-attributes-not-affecting-database-column-definition) is a relatively new property which lets you mark "attributes of a field that don’t affect a column definition". Is this helpful in any way to this situation? I tried adding this and saw no improvement, but maybe I misunderstood usage.

### Supporting code

Foo serializer (reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/#custom-serializers)):

```py
from django.db.migrations.serializer import BaseSerializer
from django.db.migrations.writer import MigrationWriter

class FooSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    def serialize(self):
        return repr(self.value), {"from myproject.utils.foo_field import Foo"}


MigrationWriter.register_serializer(Foo, FooSerializer)
```

Comment: Maybe just serialize the object and save it inside a json field?

Comment: @intelis Thanks! Better than my first thought, of writing a wrapper callable that initializes the object when called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use this code snippet to make it work -

```
class FooManagedField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, foo: Foo, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.foo: Foo = foo
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        kwargs["foo"] = "Foo"  # set a static value
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

---

---

### Long Answer

From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction)

> The counterpoint to writing your `__init__()` method is writing the
> `deconstruct()` method. It’s used during model migrations to tell Django
> how to take an instance of your new field and reduce it to a
> serialized form - in particular, what arguments to pass to `__init__()`
> to recreate it.
>
> If you haven’t added any extra options on top of the field you
> inherited from, then there’s no need to write a new `deconstruct()`
> method. If, however, you’re changing the arguments passed in
> `__init__()` (like we are in HandField), you’ll need to supplement the values being passed.

Simply put, `deconstruct()` determines whether Django needs to generate a new migration file whenever the `makemigrations` command is called.

Here, the `foo` argument doesn't take part in the DB migration, and hence, we don't need to do anything to the `deconstruct(...)` method. In other words, the following example is enough

```
class FooManagedField(models.CharField):

    def __init__(self, foo: Foo, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.foo: Foo = foo
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

But, we will get the following error,

> TypeError: Couldn't reconstruct field foo1 on polls.MyModel: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'foo'

This is because we defined the `foo` argument as mandatory/required; and thus we need to supply some value for the same from the `deconstruct(...)`

Now, we need to override the `deconstruct(...)` method by providing value for `foo` to generate migration file -

```
class FooManagedField(models.CharField):

    def __init__(self, foo: Foo, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.foo: Foo = foo
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        kwargs["foo"] = self.foo # Note that `self.foo` is a class object
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

Unfortunately, this will again raise an error -

> ValueError: Cannot serialize: Foo(1)

and this is because the `Foo` object is a custom class and Django doesn't know how to serialize them.

Setting the value with a built-in type (int, str, float, etc) will solve the issue.

```
class FooManagedField(models.CharField):

    def __init__(self, foo: Foo, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.foo: Foo = foo
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        kwargs["foo"] = str(self.foo)
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

But, this also has some issues, which is whenever the value of `self.foo` changes, a new migration file will be generated (not automatically, but upon the `makemigrations` command).

So, we are setting the value to a static value inside `deconstruct(...)` method -

```
class FooManagedField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, foo: Foo, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.foo: Foo = foo
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        kwargs["foo"] = "Foo"  # set a static value
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

---

---

**Note:** As per the documentation, the [**`non_db_attrs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-attributes-not-affecting-database-column-definition) attribute should work, but it doesn't. I'll make some tests and raise a ticket if required.

Comment: Thank you! I'm finding both edits to `deconstruct` seem to stop the problem. Can you explain why this helps? And -- does this not leave the migration broken, initializing with a string instead of the class?

Comment: (I'm also trying `non_db_attrs` but I'm not seeing it make a difference. If `kwargs["foo"]` gets a consistent string then all is well; if it gets a class, or a non-consistent string, then it isn't. `non_db_attrs` doesn't seem to change behavior in any of those situations.)

Comment: Hey @Ziv I updated the answer, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks so much! If I understand correctly -- (A) the `foo=` init argument to the `FooManagedField` will affect app behavior during runtime but presumably _won't_ affect backward or forward migration, so putting in a dummy constant value is safe. (b) I understood correctly that `non_db_attrs` _should_ solve the issue, but it doesn't and this appears to be a bug. Thanks again for this in-depth answer!

Comment: Yeah, thats right

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question: The limitation you're encountering in Django is not a hard limitation in the sense that you cannot provide a class as a default value for a field. However, it's a limitation in the way Django's migration system handles default values.

If you want to keep the `default_foo` function as it is, you can modify your model field definition to use a lambda function as the default value to provide the necessary arguments to `default_foo`.

```
class FooField(CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        default = kwargs.get("default", default_foo())
        kwargs["default"] = default_foo_callable(default)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        if kwargs.get("default") == default_foo_callable():
            del kwargs["default"]
        return name, path, args, kwargs

def default_foo_callable(value=0):
    return lambda: default_foo(value)

def default_foo(n):
    return Foo(n)
```

Modify your model definition to use the callable for the default value:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    n1 = models.IntegerField()
    n2 = models.IntegerField()
    foo1 = FooField(default=default_foo_callable(1))
    foo2 = FooField(default=default_foo_callable(2))
```

Comment: Oy. I'm seeing my example was poor! The purpose of the `foo=` parameter in the `FooField` wasn't to set a default value; it's to provide a helper class for the `Field` class. I've rewritten the example to be clearer, I hope -- removing the use of defaults, which aren't the point, and renaming `FooField` to be a `FooManagedField`, which is what I'm after. Apologies! It sounds like the same limitation you're citing for how migration handles default values, is also what I'm running up against (for serializing input parameters)?